# Mongodb, mongofiles put method.

Tags: mongodb

Good afternonn, it's afternoon in Latvia so... =) 
Presently i'm working  with mongodb, mongofiles put method, and  looks  simple, when i'm putting  files separately, but  i'm wondering how can i put a folder or  a collection of  gridfs files... ?

Thank You in advance, hope for quick reply.